# Lungo : Transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lungojs, lungo

I discovered The lungo Framework which quite Nice to use when building HTML5 mobile apps.
When changing from a section to another, you CAN use the property data-transition and specify the name of the transition you would like to use.
In the examples I found there is only one used : slide.

Are there some other values possible for the data-transition attribute?
Or is it the only transition possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx, but "pop" won't work.
The available transitions are :
- slide
- cover
- flow

Answer (score 0):

### From The Documentation It Seems you Can Specify Values That Represent Different Transitions. I believe there are more like Slide POP etc.